# What are the differences between LazyList and List in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What are the differences between the following collections types in **Scala**: `List` and `LazyList` types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LazyList` is a new type introduced in **Scala Standard Library 2.13.1**.

- The type it's an immutable one and it's placed into `scala.collection.immutable` package. The major difference between the common `List` type is the fact that the elements of the `LazyList` are computed lazily, so only those elements that are requested are computed. By this means, a lazy list can have an infinite number of elements.
- In terms of performance, the two types (`LazyList` and `List`) are comparable.
- A `LazyList` is constructed with an operator having a similar-looking to the one specific to the `List` type (`::`), `#::`.
- Being lazy, a `LazyList` can't produce a `StackOverFlowError` in a recursive loop, as an old `List` could do.

Answer (score 4):

The question

> What are the differences between `LazyList` and `List`?

can be rephrased as the question

> What are the differences between `Stream` and `List`?

because by [Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) release notes

> [`immutable.LazyList`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html) replaces `immutable.Stream`. `Stream` had
>   different laziness behavior and is now deprecated. ([#7558](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7558),
>   [#7000](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7000))

and the answer to the rephrased question is provided by [what is the difference between Scala Stream vs Scala List vs Scala Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50485355/5205022).

Performance judgements are best addressed by [measurements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035954/5205022) within particular scenarios.